# (Unity)How to make an animation for hundreds of figures(very similar in appearance) in one time?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating a restaurant mobile game and it will have hundreds of customers who are very similar in appearance.(ex:just hairstyle,hair color, clothes color different.)

Is there any method to create their animations(ex: walking) in one time without repetitive procedure？

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Are you asking how to set animations with offsets so they don't all animate the exact same way?  Or are you asking how to specify an animation for every single character all at once?

Comment: What I am asking is the latter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. You have to do it for each character individually.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your characters use the same `Animator Controller`, you can set a default animation to use within that controller.

Otherwise, no, there is no "Apply animation to all" command available.

You can accomplish essentially the same task with scripting.  Apply a script to all your characters, like a "MyAnimation" script, and within that script's Update loop watch for changes to a static variable.  Then when you change the value of that variable, have each character update their animation accordingly.  I don't think that's necessarily the best way to do it, but it is a pretty quick way.

```
public class MyAnimation: MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator _animator = null;

    public static string AllAnimationsName = null;

    string _lastAnimationName = null;
    
    void Start()
    {
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (_lastAnimationName != AllAnimationsName)
        {
             _lastAnimationName = AllAnimationsName;
             //TODO:: Apply the animation to the characters animator such as:
             //_animator.CrossFade(_lastAnimationName);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, not the best way to do it but it should allow you to quickly control all the characters with the script applied to them without iterating through each.